# PTP time sync over PPP (on serial) connection

Tags: linux

I am running 2 ARM devices:

- devA is connected to Ethernet network with all of its NICs
- devB has the LCD, buttons and all this things for user interfacing, but no NIC and no RTC battery

Both devices run on kernel 4.9 provided by Texas Instruments.

Current time should be displayed on LCD (devB), but as mentioned there is no RTC battery, so after power down system time is kinda random... On the other hand devB has RTC with battery, NTP and PTPv2 client.

Both devices are connected with pppd over serial connection (RS422) which creates TCP/IP network between them.

I tried pushing time with NTP, but it takes lots of time before ntpd client on devB decides that it's ready to grab time  from devA (sometimes it could go to an hour or more).  Now to have close-to-real time on LCD I'm forcing new time with *ssh* and *date*. That is far from what could be called *good solution*.

I tried to setup PTP synchronisation between them, but it seems that *ppp0* interface has no timestamping available. Here is output from *ethtool*:

```
# ethtool -T ppp0
Time stamping parameters for ppp0:
Capabilities:
    software-receive      (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_RX_SOFTWARE)
    software-system-clock (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_SOFTWARE)
PTP Hardware Clock: none
Hardware Transmit Timestamp Modes: none
Hardware Receive Filter Modes: none
```

If I'm right the thing I'm missing here is the capability `software-transmit (SOF_TIMESTAMPING_TX_SOFTWARE)`

Is it possible to create ppp connection supporting PTP? If so, how can I achieve this? Alternatively, is there some other way to properly synchronize those devices?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a pretty specific network time sync question. I think this will be better asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com or maybe https://superuser.com/

Comment: As random idea, why not just run the ntpdate command to pull the time over the PPP link, triggered by the onUP script for the PPP daemon?

Comment: I'm currently doing something like that, but the clock in this device is terrible, and before the ntpd kicks in, that time is few seconds away again.
About off-topic - I was pretty sure I have better chance finding here, in IoT, someone that dealt with some similar issue.

Comment: If the clock drift is that bad you could just run ntpdate via cron every 10mins